# Можно ли сдать ЕГЭ по информатике на Swift?

Tags: swift, информатика

В последних заданиях ЕГЭ по информатике пишут, что нужно указать язык и его версию. Но у меня сомнения по поводу Swift'a. Он ведь не компилируется на Windows. Не поставят ли мне 0 баллов, если я напишу программу на Swift'e? Вдруг они будут оперировать тем, что им проблемно найти где-нибудь Mac OS, установить на него Xcode и только тогда запустить программу. PascalABC.NET – это, конечно, неплохой язык, но профессионально работать с ним я не буду, а со Swift'ом поработать было бы неплохо.

Comment: Вам следует адресовать этот вопрос непосредстенно проверяющей организации, чтобы уточнить правила этого года. Но я бы советовал придерживаться более простых и надежных вариантов. Если вы будете профессионально работать, то изучить 2 языка не проблема, а даже преимущество - расширяет понимание.

Comment: пишите на том языке, который учили в школе, а не сами. ЕГЭ для проверки школьных знаний нужен

Comment: @eri я бы не был так уверен, на самом деле. ЕГЭ проверяет что угодно, но не знания. Да и я не знаю, в какой школе нужно учиться, чтобы школьная программа нормально готовила к той же информатике. С-часть вряд ли даже издали затрагивается в школьных программах.

Comment: Swift - это же С-подобный язык? Тогда, наверное, будет нетрудно выучить C/C++/C#/Java/JS/PHP и писать на нём.

Comment: Этот вопрос скорее не о программировании, а юридический. Сожалею, но мы не сможем дать на него достоверный ответ. Kromster прав, вопрос нужно задавать проверяющей организации. Субъективно: конечно, никто не будет ради вас покупать мак. Рассчитывайте на то, что вам предоставят то же, что и остальным сдающим.